# How to switch between passing different props to a vue component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to pass different data to a vue component by clicking a button.
I am not sure what the best practice would be for this.

This is how i imagined it, but I don't really know how to implement it.

```js
import TableComp from "./TableComp";

export default {
  components: {
    TableComp
  },

  data() {
    return {
      data1: {
        Name: "John"
      },
      data2: {
        Name: "Allice"
      },
      data3: {
        Name: "Erick"
      },
      selectedData: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    select: function(name) {
      this.selectedData = this.name;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button name="data1" @click="select(name)">data1</button>
    <button name="data2" @click="select(name)">data2</button>
    <button name="data3" @click="select(name)">data3</button>
    <button></button>
    <table-comp v-bind:data="selectedData"></table-comp>
  </div>
</template>
```

I know this doesn't work, but is it possible to pass button name into a method like this or is there a nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `this` from `this.name` since you are passing the value as a param into the method.

```
methods: {
    select: function(name) {
      this.selectedData = name;
    }
  }
```

---

I would also suggest you to convert the 3 different names into and array and use the `v-for` helper to render the buttons.

Example:

```
data() {
  names: ["John", "Alice", "Eric"]
}
```

The button:

```
<button v-for="name in names" :key="name" @click="select(name)">{{name}}</button>
```

Comment: Ok this works, if i change the method select. 
But is this the best way of doing this?

Comment: I would assume so since you do not have to hardcode for each object.

Answer (score 0):

While you could do it that way, you also have other options that would work well, depending on your project needs. They are all valid ways to achieve what you want. 
You can use vuex to manage your states and you can also use events. To use events,

```
<button name="data1" @click="select(name)">data1</button>

methods:{
    select(name){
          this.$emit('click-event', name)
    }
}
```

And in your child component you can listen for this event;

```
<listening-component @click-event='doSomething'></listening-component>
```

Then write the `doSomething` method to achieve what you want.